# How to sync git tags on a fork with upstream?

Tags: git

I have an upstream repository that deleted some tags because they were old and no longer useful. I know I can get rid of those tags locally with `git fetch -p -P`.

But I also have a remote fork of this repository. How can I prune my local tags and then make sure the old tags are also deleted from my fork?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+remote+tags

Answer (score 1):

If you sure about your local is updated with all the necessary tags after removing unnecessary tags then I would recommend **removing all remote (fork) tags then push your local all tags to the fork**.

```
# remove all remote tags, assuming 'origin' is your fork
$ git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)

# push all local tags to remote
$ git push --tags
```